# The FAQ link on main no longer fits in Chrome

Tags: bug, design

Starting today, this is what I see:

> [image: Chrome 22.0.1229.79 m, Vista]

This only happens in Chrome (22.0.1229.79 m) and only on the main site. Meta looks fine. Other SE sites look fine. Not reproducible in Opera, FF, IE, or Safari.

Restarted and all. Tried swapping "tools" for "review" because it's shorter. Same difference.

No idea what's going on or whether anyone else is affected at all, but I thought I'd mention it.

**Edit.** Probably related:

> [image: Review stats]

Again, only in Chrome, only on ELU main.

**Edit 2.** Yet another example:

> [image: Badge sliced up]

Looks fine everywhere except in Chrome.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128524/google-maps-api-v3-in-chrome-wrong-controls-and-not-responding-correctly It appears that version of Chrome has a number of problems.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: That's an unrelated problem on an earlier version. I have Chrome 22.0.1229.79 m, same as OP here, and I don't have his problem. So far as I know, Chrome *always* updates itself to latest version - I seriously doubt there's an option to disable this behaviour. So maybe the problem is OP has an unrealistic setting for "minimum font size" or something.

Comment: @F It's not an earlier version: the comments indicate an error made it from beta into release. While the issue *may* be unrelated, it may also be related to Chrome's OS/hardware detection (which is what the SO question is about). It would probably be helpful if Reg could give some details of his hardware, and specifically whether it has touch-screen support or not and whether that's active.

Comment: @Andrew: A 4½-year old low-end HP PC with Windows Vista Home Something. I don't think touch screens existed back then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine again in Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m.